# Porta Brace audio recorder case AR7 design fault? 

Tags: cases

I have just purchased Porta Brace AR7 for my Sound Devices 702 and I am utterly disapointed with it.

It has a major design fault!!!! Velcro strips on the sides that protect recorder from sliding left/right are in a totally wrong place. They obstruct headphone volume potentiometer and input. I find this very frustrating considering that the case cost me 180$ .

Is it just me or other users have the same issue with this product???

I tried to get in touch with Porta Brace and asked them if they could modify it for me but unfortunately no joy!!!

Anyone considering to get one of these......don't bother. There are few more alternatives that are much better but  i  found them to late . Too bad!

http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound-Bags?q=node/1168

Comment: That petrol bag is the one i'm using and it's working great for me to.

Comment: I hate that bag, ended up buying a petrol bag... 

Comment: I cut them to half their length and it is not so bad. But yes, annoying!

Comment: I use Petrol bags as well.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have this issue. I would sometimes get annoyed that the bag's side panes would close at the wrong times, but if you spend some time "working out" those panels it is a quite useful and durable bag.  It you play around with it you can use the velcro to almost keep the panels "permanently" open.